# Compiling a 64-bit DLL with CodeBlocks gives linker errors

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker, 64-bit

I have prepared a very simple DLL program in C++, on Windows 7 64-bit. I've made two versions, 64-bit and 32-bit. The 32-bit project I compile with linker and compiler set with the `-m32` flag. I use `-std=c++11`. Here is its code:

main.h

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

// a sample exported function
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            MessageBoxA(0, "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH", "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            MessageBoxA(0, "DLL_PROCESS_DETACH", "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            MessageBoxA(0, "DLL_THREAD_ATTACH", "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            MessageBoxA(0, "DLL_THREAD_DETACH", "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

The DLL compiles fine and works well in the 32-bit version. But when I compile to 64-bit by removing the `-m32` option on everything, I get a linker error:

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp_MessageBoxA'|

Replacing with `-m64` does not help. Here is my MingW version details:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=E:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-cxx-flags=-DWINPTHREAD_STATIC --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-1 --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)
```

What could I be doing wrong? Could it be that I need to include a special 64-bit windows header? Many thanks for any direction! :)

Comment: I know, this is just for testing, but do not call `MessageBox` from `DllMain` (see [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx)). Calling [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) is safe, though. As an aside, since you are using Code::Blocks and are subject to its poor choice of default settings: You should absolutely, positively be calling the Unicode versions of the Windows API (i.e. `MessageBoxW` instead of `MessageBoxA`).

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, I'm an idiot. Long ago, I had set `-m32` as a permanent flag in the linker settings under "Compiler and debugger." Removed it, works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

this is easy, you just set the Global Compiler Settings, then set the Compiler Flag, select General C++ 14 GNU C++, Good luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).